# Clearing Excel combobox takes too long

Tags: vba, excel

UPDATE: It looks like its actually the .clear that is making things so slow

So I have three comboboxes in three sheets (one in each) and when I am updating or refreshing the comboboxes the process takes about 15 seconds to finish for just 5 items. When the actual data is entered there could be over 50 items so this performance isn't acceptable.

The data source is a table which is connected to an access query.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Excel or if my code is that bad. Maybe I should consider data validation list instead of a combobox.

Here is my code

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.PGcustomer.Clear
    Sheet3.PGcustomer.Clear
    Sheet4.PGcustomer.Clear
Dim dataSet As Range

Set dataSet = Sheet2.Range("Customers[Customer]")
    Dim data() As String
    Dim dataSize As Integer
    Dim dictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long

    dataSize = dataSet.Rows.Count
    Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    ReDim data(dataSize)
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        data(i) = dataSet.Cells(i, 1).Value    '<<< using Cells
        dictionary(data(i)) = 1
    Next i

    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In dictionary.Keys()
        Sheet1.PGcustomer.AddItem v
        Sheet3.PGcustomer.AddItem v
        Sheet4.PGcustomer.AddItem v
    Next v

Sheet1.PGcustomer.ListIndex = 0
Sheet3.PGcustomer.ListIndex = 0
Sheet4.PGcustomer.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have code behind the comboboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Never iterate through cells unless you really have to. You can get the values from the range using this:

```
Dim vValues
vValues = ThisWorkbook.Names("Customers[Customer]").Value
```

vValues will now contain an array of the values from your range which you can iterate directly instead of loading them into a Dictionary object - Dictionary objects are also quite costly so should only be used if you really need them.

Comment: Good tips. Although I use Dictionaries very frequently and have not had any real performance issues with them (I find them easier to use than `Collection` objects), this particular case is not well-suited for a dictionary and definitely does not need to do cells/range iteration to store the values in an array.

Comment: I would assume the Dictionary is to get a unique list. It would be faster to use the List property rather than AddItem when populating the controls though.